# Resizing the tableView's tableHeaderView to account for an attributedText?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to make sure that my `headerView` inside a `tableView` is dynamically growing to account for the size of my attributed string.

This concept works fine with just autolayout for my cell-views without much work.

However I am having problems with the header (a UIView) and so I am trying to calculate it's height by hand but for some reason the height given by this code is too small?

```
 func setupTableHeader () {
    let str = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    let attributedStr = NSAttributedString(string: str)
    headerViewLabel.attributedText = attributedStr

    let rect = attributedStr.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100000000000000000), options: [.usesFontLeading, .usesLineFragmentOrigin], context: nil)

    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    let height = rect.height
    headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.width, height: height + headerView.frame.height)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension on `NSAttributedString` that calculates a height based on a given width:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func height(forConstantWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintBox = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let calculatedBox = boundingRect(with: constraintBox, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        return calculatedBox.height
    }
}
```

You could call that and pass in the table view's width, like:

`let height = myAttrString.height(forConstantWidth: tableView.frame.size.width)`

Comment: Sadly this does not work for me either. I am getting a height that is off by a factor of about 2 or 3.  .... This is big enough but with too much padding at the top and bottom: 
headerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.width - 20, height: height * 3 + headerView.frame.height)

Comment: It seems you are multiplying the height by 3. Is that something we should know about

Comment: I’ll second @agibson007 ‘s question

Comment: I am and sorry I see how that seems confusing but that was to illustrate that without that, it's way too short. 2x is too short too. The text gets truncated and shows ellipsis.  Somewhere between 2x and 3x is where the true height is.

Comment: Sometimes core text can be more accurate but sometimes not but I would bet that it is accurate in this case.

Comment: To be honest, this particular API has always been a bit frustrating to me. Why not use an intrinsic content size?

Comment: I am having problems with this particular header view, the header not growing with the label, which is strange since it works fine if I set up my auto-layout for a row cell, it's just a header that gives me problems.  I did consider making a special first row but that would be a bit ugly.  This is why I am trying this other route. Maybe seeing if there are any examples of an Xcode project with this working? I can provide one with it not working if that would help?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `UITableView's` header resize to account for size of its Sub Elements.

You can use following extension.

```
extension UITableView {
    func automaticHeaderViewSize() {
        if let headerView = self.tableHeaderView {

            let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
            var headerFrame = headerView.frame

            //Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
            if height != headerFrame.size.height {
                headerFrame.size.height = height
                headerView.frame = headerFrame
                self.tableHeaderView = headerView
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure, your label has `numberOfLines = 0`.

So, finally your code is going to be (according to your question).

```
 func setupTableHeader () {
    let str = "your long text..."
    let attributedStr = NSAttributedString(string: str)
    headerViewLabel.attributedText = attributedStr
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    tableView.automaticHeaderViewSize()
}
```